# What is this soft curved brushstroke-like effect?

Tags: effect, special-effects

I can call myself as nerd but this time I'm stuck, I couldn't  find any information about a filter or effect. All I know is; there is a Photoshop brush set.

How can people do that effect like one in this example? Is it automatic or you have to use specific brush or what?

[image]

Comment: Its not the accented edges brush strokes filter over a photo is it?

Comment: It would be _very_, _very_ helpful if you could describe your impression of the effect briefly in the title and in more detail in the question. Short "what is this?" questions have three problems. First, answerers may not see what you find interesting in the photo, so it's best to be clear about what you're wondering about. Second, no one looking for the exact same thing is likely to ever find this in a search, because there's nothing distinct to key off of. And finally, people who were looking for some completely other effect may stumble across this, which doesn't help anyone.

Comment: You are completely right but If I could describe anything I would google it first. So I've added the photo and it's my words. Thanks.

Comment: See also [How can I achive this soft-curved effect in photoshop?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/37284/how-can-i-achive-this-soft-curved-effect-in-photoshop) and 
[What technique was used to acheive this soft-curves-brush-stroke effect?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/35931/what-software-or-technique-was-used-to-acheive-this-soft-curves-brush-stroke-e)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Topaz Clean](http://www.topazlabs.com/clean/#3) can achieve similar results: http://gallery.topazlabs.com/keyword/clean?forceView=1360425932182#!p=2&n=10

But plugin used for this photo is most likely **Fractalius**: http://www.redfieldplugins.com/filterFractalius.htm

Comment: Looks very much like Fractalius to me

Answer (score 1):

My first guess was Topaz Clean, as @marcinwolny suggested.  It's a plugin that works globally, not a brush set, but I think it approximates the effect in that image. Here is a before and after I've done quickly to show what Topaz can do.

[image]

- Applied Topaz Clean (Curly Smooth filter)
- Duplicated the layer - guassian blur (15-20 pixels) - blend mode screen - to lighten and give it a glow

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [G'Mic's filters](https://gmicol.greyc.fr/)
Here are some similar filters that they have
 - artistic -> Rodilius
 - artistic -> painting
 - artistic -> Whirl drawing

Comment: That doesn't really seem very similar to this effect in results.