# How can I achieve this soft-curved effect in photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, effect

I once used some Android application to add some effect on one of my photos. I forgot the app name and I never found it. Can I achieve this effect using Photoshop?

[image: the effect].

Comment: Do you have a copy of what the image originally looked like as well?  I do agree that it isn't an emboss now that I have seen it on a higher quality display than my phone, but it's hard to visualize what the original looked like to see what modifications may have been made.

Comment: Can you describe the effect you are looking for in words? Editing the question to include this info will both get better answers for you, and also increases the chance that someone with the same interest will ever find the question later. Right now, even if this gets a great answer, someone else might wonder the exact same thing as the title but actually about an entirely different effect.

Comment: I will try my best but as I don't come from photography background so I may not able to describe those effects properly. That is why i attached the image so that it could speak for it self.

Comment: Same effect as this I think - [Name this filter/effect?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/34504/name-this-filter-effect/34512#34512) - there is also another question recently that used that same curly effect on a tree overhanging a house - my search skills are failing me

Comment: Found it, was closed [soft-curves-brush-stroke effect](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/35931/what-software-or-technique-was-used-to-acheive-this-soft-curves-brush-stroke-e)

Comment: Huh. Apparently all of these _are_ looking for that same effect. :)

Comment: Also, wow: the phone view given by google docs really masks the effect!

Comment: I was asking about the very same effect and my question was closed. @MikeW linked it above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any native effects in Photoshop that will do that. But I spotted this tool from Adobe Labs called [Pixel Bender](http://sharedart.blogspot.ca/2012/05/beautiful-oil-painting-effect-in.html). It is a PhotoShop add-on. I haven't used it myself, but that example photo looks like a very similar effect. It also looks like the tools are highly customizable.

[image: PixelBender preview]

Of course, that doesn't discount the possibilty of combining a few methods with just Photoshop by itself to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Thanks dude this is what i need but in gray scale.