# Oil Paint Effect app or Software

Tags: software, effect, reverse-engineering, apps

I'm looking for an `app` or `software` to do this effect on my photos. I searched and found some free `photoshop` action but neither not do this exactly, I'm wonder to know which mobile `app` or `computer software` can do this? if it's photoshop action, can someone tell me the name? or app name.

[image]

Comment: Can you be more descriptive about what, exactly, in this photo you are trying to replicate? It could be argued that shooting under the correct lighting conditions for such a look (in this case the "golden hour") is the most paramount consideration, not any particular post processing technique.

Comment: @MichaelClark I told in my Post. I want effect/filter of this photo. that like Oil Paint effect.

Comment: "Oil Paint effect" is awful broad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is this soft curved brushstroke-like effect?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/34504/what-is-this-soft-curved-brushstroke-like-effect)

Answer (score 1):

This effect is more than an app or software can replicate. This was done via a combination of brushing over the original photo using the smear brush or regular brush with color sampled from the image in photoshop. It's basically a form of digital painting to convert a real photo into a painting. Take a look at this [course](https://www.lynda.com/Painter-tutorials/Digital-Painting-Transforming-Portrait/126125-2.html) from Lynda.

For simpler automated effect (most of the time will not be perfect) check [Topaz Labs](https://www.topazlabs.com/) they have couple of plugins that could achieve what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the best software to do any type of digital painting is Corel Painter http://www.painterartist.com/us/product/paint-program/

You can make some automated process, or grab your drawing tablet and do a personalized job.

Another one interesting, where you can adjust a lot of parameters is filter Forge https://www.filterforge.com/ You need to find one filter combination you like or prepare one yourself via nodes. There is a free trial. You can use it standalone or as Photoshop Plugin.

Of course you can try Photoshop itself or Gimp painting over a photo.

And there other several options where a simple google search will give results. https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=oil+painting+software I am only quoting the ones I have used.

If you are upt to the challenge you can also try MyPaint http://mypaint.org/about/ and paint above a photo.

---

I have not tried this one. (My BitDefender marks a warning, but I have the feeling it is a false positive) but looks promising: postworkshop.net

Answer (score 1):

If you have Adobe Photoshop you can find this effect under the filters tab. 
Go to Filters>Oil Paint...  Adjust the sliders to get the desired effect.(Keep the 'Shine' slider at zero).

Comment: I have not this option on my photoshop

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be Topaz Glow.
http://www.topazlabs.com/glow

Comment: Could you provide an example to argue you point ? As it is, this one-link answer will be deleted. Topaz Glow doesn't seem likely if one is just looking at their website.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/40234)

Comment: @Olivier Product question answered by product name and product link with examples. I don't see any value in adding more words in this case.